# How to get JSON data directly from the database table?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, datatable

A column on my database table contains below JSON serialized string.

```
Table: school_details

school_id     class_json

25            {
              "class_id": "1377",
              "class_name": "XXX",
               "No.of students": "100"
              }

25                {
             "class_id": "1378",
             "class_name": "YYX",
             "No.of students": "80"
                }
```

Now I want to read this data and send it as a JSON array as shown in the 'Expected output' below. But I got a different output when doing like below. How should I change the code to get the desired output? Is this a good practice to store JSON directly as above in the database table? or else need to convert it to the string before storing it in the database?

```
   string school_id="25";
   string status="success";
   sql = "SELECT class_json FROM school_details WHERE school_id @school_id";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@school_id", school_id);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
               dt.Load(dr);
                status = "success";
            }
           var getData = new { status, school_id,Class_Deatils=dt };
        return getData;
```

Output:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "school_id": "25",
  "Class_Deatils": [
 {
  "class_json ": "{\n  \"class_id\": \"1377\",\n  \"class_name\": \"XXX\",\n  \"No.of students\": \"100\"\n  }"
        },
 {
  "class_json ": "{\n  \"class_id\": \"1378\",\n  \"class_name\": \"YYX\",\n  \"No.of students\": \"80\"\n  }"
        }
  ]
  }
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "school_id": "25",
  "Class_Deatils": [{
  "class_id": "1377",
  "class_name": "XXX",
  "No.of students": "100"
  },
  {
  "class_id": "1378",
  "class_name": "YYX",
  "No.of students": "80"
  }
  ]
  }
```

Comment: You need to deserialize the JSON into an object (perhaps custom classes you make to represent the data).

Comment: You are aware that \n are newline? Are they visible like that in the string?  This looks a lot like the string was coded for visualization in a debugger. Where do you get the output from? And PLEASE consider NOT using a data table.

Comment: You should really normalize that JSON into another table. By the way, you are missing `using` blocks on your connection, command and reader objects

Answer (score 1):

The result that you get in `class_json` is actually an escaped string, not a pure json.
If you want to use it as a json, you can use the `JObject.Parse()` method.

Here's how to do that:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string class_json_str = "{\n  \"class_id\": \"1377\",\n  \"class_name\": \"XXX\",\n  \"No.of students\": \"100\"\n  }";
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(class_json_str );
        
        // Now you have a JSON objects which contains the data.
        // You can access it's properties like this 
        var classId = o["class_id"];
        Console.WriteLine(classId);

        // In case you want to make a string again, use the following
        var jsonString = o.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
    }
}
```

---

P.S. The best practice would be to properly deserialize it as a class instead of playing with it as a json.
And then serialize back when sending to the front-end.
For more info see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Answer (score 0):

I propose you use serialization and deserialization for saving and retrieving JSON data from your database, it can help you in preventing problems and you can have good control over your JSON data. you can use the Newtonsoft library for serialization and deserialization very easily.

to see the examples visit https://www.newtonsoft.com/json